# Edit Firestore collectionGroup query documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering if it is possible to update the fields of a document from a collectionGroup query. I have set up my query as below and I want to .update() a single field in the document the query returns.

```
Query query = db.collectionGroup("orders").whereEqualTo("restaurantid",fAuth.getUid()).whereEqualTo(docId,getId());

        query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                    Order order = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).toObject(Order.class);
                    //can i update the document here?


                }else
                {
                        Log.d("STATUS ERROR", "QUERY IS EMPTY");
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please share your `Order` class. and any update to document is possible with `update` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write to a document in Firestore you need a `DocumentReference` to it. Your `queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0)` gives you a `DocumentSnapshot`, which has a [`getReference` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getReference()). So:

```
Query query = db.collectionGroup("orders").whereEqualTo("restaurantid",fAuth.getUid()).whereEqualTo(docId,getId());

query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0);

            // Order order = snapshot.toObject(Order.class);

            DocumentReference ref = snapshot.getReference();

            ref.update("fieldName", "value");

        } else {
            Log.d("STATUS ERROR", "QUERY IS EMPTY");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update value of any document with its reference and `update` method.

```java
DocumentReference washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC");
washingtonRef.update(key, value);
```